# Is there a way in Bash and Zsh that says, if the variable is an empty string, make it 0?

Tags: bash, zsh

I understand the empty string in Bash is falsy, and we should be able to use something like

```
a=""
b=($a || 0)
```

which means if `$a` is falsy, then just make it 0. But it gave

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
```

and I understand we can use `[-z $a]` and use the Bash ternary form:

```
a=""
[[ -z $a ]] && b=0 || b=$a
```

But is there a way to use something similar to the first form above that works in both Bash and Zsh?

Comment: (the duplicate doesn't ask about zsh explicitly, but the answers suggest POSIXy syntax that, while not a standard-compliant shell, zsh does support).

Comment: If you intend to use the variable in an arithmetic context, and empty or unset variable *already* defaults to zero, as long as you don't explicitly expand it. `unset b; `echo $((3 + b))` outputs 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter expansion: `${PARAMETER:-WORD}` will, if the variable `PARAMETER` is unset or an empty string, evaluate to `WORD`, otherwise the value of `PARAMETER`.

So:

```
b=${a:-0}
```